# NetCDF Python Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('<U32') to dtype('float32')

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-xarray, netcdf4

I'm attempting to load a netCDF into a dataframe with either xarray, or with the netCDF4 library. Normally this wouldn't be an issue as my netCDFs come with their latitude, longitude, and data values in Float32 for the most part. I'm assuming my error is because I have some datatypes being delivered as Float64.

I'm currently receiving the same error from both libraries on load, presumably because they both make use of numpy. I'm not doing any math - just loading.

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('<U32') 
to dtype('float32') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

using print(netCDF4.Dataset("d:\netdcdf.nc") yields the following description:

```
dimensions(sizes): time(1), lon(841), lat(681)
variables(dimensions): float64 time(time), float64 lon(lon), 
    float64 lat(lat), int32 crs(), float32 deadpool(time, lat, lon)
```

My script is below, and includes both load examples for xarray and netCDF4.

```
#This file is designed to convert netcdf files to the BOM standard format. 

import netCDF4
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputfile = 'D:\\Temp\\WeatherDownloads\\Weather\\deadpool.aus.nc'

    #xarray setup, debug and load
    ncx = xr.open_dataset(inputfile)
    ncdf = ncx.deadpool.to_dataframe() #fails here if we use xarray

    print(ncdf.head(10))


    #NetCDF4 setup, debug and load
    nc = netCDF4.Dataset(inputfile, mode='r')
    nc.variables.keys()

    lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
    lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
    time = nc.variables['time']
    datavar = nc.variables['deadpool'][:] #fails here if we use netCDF4

    print("The dtype of lat is: " + str(dtype(lat)))
    print("The dtype of lon is: " + str(dtype(lon)))
    print("The dtype of time is: " + str(dtype(time)))
    print("The dtype of datavar is: " + str(dtype(datavar)))

    data_ts = pd.Series(datavar, index=time)

    print(data_ts.head(10))
```

Comment: 'U32' is unicode string

Comment: Second time today you've pointed something out I've missed entirely. Nice work. Have you got a strategy for how I could work out which variable might be getting treated as U32? When I look at the print(r) output for the netCDF everything looks like it should be numeric.

Comment: For numpy arrays `arr.dtype` tells us.  Also `print(repr(arr))` gives more information than the regular print.

Comment: For anyone who might find this in the future - I was unable to resolve this issue, and I was similarly unable to determine why it was happening. What I wound up doing instead was installing GDAL for Python (wheel file, not the windows executable environment), using a one liner to convert an alternate file type (ERDAS IMAGINE) to netcdf, then use xarray to add a time dimension, set metadata and rename dimensions and variables as I needed. That effort was maybe 10-15 lines and pretty straightforward. GDAL was the key to get the translation working as it includes error corrections etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem looking at netCDF files + xarray. The error I got is:

> UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('float32'), dtype('<U5')) -> None here

While the error is same, I cannot 100% state that what I am getting is exactly what you are getting. But I can describe what I found out and maybe it solves your issue.

My issue has to due with decoding. Some field variables come with `_FillValue`,`scale` and `add_offset` in their attributes per CF conventions. These are usually of int or float types. You can check what this values are in xarray by doing:

```py
ds = xr.open_dataset(filename)

ds[varName].attributes # this returns a dictionary
```

where varName is some field numeric variable like temperature, velocity, etc.

The problem in my case, and probably what is going on in your case as well, is that the values for `_FillValue` or `scale` in the attributes for that variable, are strings. They should be numeric...

`xarray` can sometime be tricky for debugging this kind of issue because `xarray` successfully creates a lazy view of the dataset, and it is only until you try to load/plot the data is when the the `scale/fill_value/add_offset` operations get triggered and the error shows up - despite no math being performed on the user side.

#### solution

In my case this worked:

```py
ds = xr.open_dataset(filename, mask_and_scale=False) # 
ds[var].attributes[attr] = float(ds[var].attributes[attr])
nds = xr.decode(ds)
```

where `attr` is one of `[Fill_value, scale, add_offset]` related operations, or all of them. You want to inspect the `datatype` of your data variable and which attributes has a string type instead of numeric. In this case turning the `string` into `float` works, but you should prob match the data type.